# TCPDF draws <defs> tags

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF and I have a problem with it. Currently I am trying to render a pie chart made with D3.js but TCPDF is drawing something that it should not and I think that they are the *defs* tags.

Here is how it looks in HTML: http://s33.postimg.org/fnwvr0e8f/chart.png

Here is how it looks in PDF: http://s33.postimg.org/czcnel2bz/chart.png

And here is the code:

```html
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="635.3488372093024" height="350">
<defs xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad0">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(36, 132, 193);"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient>
        <radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad1">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(101, 166, 32);"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient>
        <radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad2">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(123, 104, 136);"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient>
        <radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad3">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(160, 93, 86);"/>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient>
</defs>
        
        <g class="p0_lineGroups" style="opacity: 1;">
        <g class="p0_lineGroup">
        <path d="M406.60807731424296,185.06425429843085L409.2728804615161,184.9194897323535C411.93768360878926,184.77472516627614,417.2672899033356,184.48519603412143,422.59689619788196,183.35884327935165C427.9265024924283,182.23249052458183,433.25610878697466,180.26931414719692,435.92091193424784,179.28772595850447L438.5857150815211,178.30613776981204" stroke="#2484c1" stroke-width="1" fill="none" style="opacity: 1;"/></g>
        <g class="p0_lineGroup">
        <path d="M236.58273629241512,225.17613747072312L235.36047483671888,225.69125176104222C234.1382133810227,226.20636605136139,231.6936904696303,227.23659463199965,226.80464464684547,228.3637184599429C221.9155988240607,229.49084228788615,214.58203008988352,230.71486136313436,210.9152457227949,231.32687090075845L207.24846135570633,231.9388804383826" stroke="#65a620" stroke-width="1" fill="none" style="opacity: 1;"/></g>
        <g class="p0_lineGroup">
        <path d="M270.9320048548812,112.76264622496167L267.5595591997975,111.1862892989631C264.1871135447137,109.60993237296452,257.4422222345463,106.45721852096736,252.945628027768,103.42207595296925C248.4490338209897,100.38693338497116,246.20073671760056,97.46936210097212,245.07658816590597,96.0105764589726L243.95243961421144,94.55179081697307" stroke="#7b6888" stroke-width="1" fill="none" style="opacity: 1;"/></g>
        <g class="p0_lineGroup">
        <path d="M302.8970629134642,100.73537296395465L302.0244215219816,97.03742519558193C301.151780130499,93.33947742720923,299.4064973475338,85.94358189046385,298.24297549222365,80.07965153263359C297.07945363691357,74.21572117480332,296.4976927092585,69.8837559958882,296.20681224543097,67.71777340643064L295.91593178160343,65.55179081697307" stroke="#a05d56" stroke-width="1" fill="none" style="opacity: 1;"/></g></g>
        
        <g transform="translate(317.6744186046512,188.5)" class="p0_pieChart">
        <g class="p0_arc" transform="rotate(0)">
        <path id="p0_segment0" fill="url(#p0_grad0)" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 1;" d="M5.449678256205722e-15,-89A89,89 0 0,1 6.866369340141512,88.73473374099211L0,0Z" data-index="0"/></g><g class="p0_arc" transform="rotate(175.57522123893807)">
        <path id="p0_segment1" fill="url(#p0_grad1)" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 1;" d="M5.449678256205722e-15,-89A89,89 0 0,1 56.99721760166694,68.35435015906617L0,0Z" data-index="1"/></g><g class="p0_arc" transform="rotate(315.7522123893806)">
        <path id="p0_segment2" fill="url(#p0_grad2)" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 1;" d="M5.449678256205722e-15,-89A89,89 0 0,1 37.799801202416305,-80.57403445935797L0,0Z" data-index="2"/></g><g class="p0_arc" transform="rotate(340.8849557522124)">
        <path id="p0_segment3" fill="url(#p0_grad3)" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 1;" d="M5.449678256205722e-15,-89A89,89 0 0,1 29.1444744003596,-84.09280356800328L0,0Z" data-index="3"/></g></g>
        <text id="p0_title" class="p0_title" x="320.1744186046512" y="27" text-anchor="middle" fill="black" style="font-size: 20px; font-family: sans-serif;">Distribución paradas por causas</text><text x="320.1744186046512" y="87" id="p0_subtitle" class="p0_subtitle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: sans-serif;">


        </text><text x="5" y="345" id="p0_footer" class="p0_footer" text-anchor="left" fill="#999999" style="font-size: 0px; font-family: sans-serif;"/><defs><radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad0"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(36, 132, 193);"/><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient><radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad1"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(101, 166, 32);"/><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient><radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad2"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(123, 104, 136);"/><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient><radialGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="0" cy="0" r="120%" id="p0_grad3"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(160, 93, 86);"/><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"/></radialGradient></defs><g class="p0_labels-inner"><g id="p0_labelGroup0-inner" data-index="0" class="p0_labelGroup-inner" transform="translate(356.0820067766466,189.59125238801715)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentPercentage0-inner" class="p0_segmentPercentage-inner" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">49%</text></g><g id="p0_labelGroup1-inner" data-index="1" class="p0_labelGroup-inner" transform="translate(261.62348398674226,211.8756319281795)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentPercentage1-inner" class="p0_segmentPercentage-inner" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">39%</text></g><g id="p0_labelGroup2-inner" data-index="2" class="p0_labelGroup-inner" transform="translate(283.7064109658901,149.42369234720093)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentPercentage2-inner" class="p0_segmentPercentage-inner" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">7%</text></g><g id="p0_labelGroup3-inner" data-index="3" class="p0_labelGroup-inner" transform="translate(301.4647765539917,142.7418738688637)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentPercentage3-inner" class="p0_segmentPercentage-inner" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">5%</text></g></g><g class="p0_labels-outer"><g id="p0_labelGroup0-outer" data-index="0" class="p0_labelGroup-outer" transform="translate(444.5857150815211,183.90613776981203)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentMainLabel0-outer" class="p0_segmentMainLabel-outer" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Desconocido</text><text id="p0_segmentValue0-outer" class="p0_segmentValue-outer" dy="14" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(173, 173, 173);">9.92</text></g><g id="p0_labelGroup1-outer" data-index="1" class="p0_labelGroup-outer" transform="translate(146.24846135570633,237.5388804383826)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentMainLabel1-outer" class="p0_segmentMainLabel-outer" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Descanso</text><text id="p0_segmentValue1-outer" class="p0_segmentValue-outer" dy="14" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(173, 173, 173);">7.92</text></g><g id="p0_labelGroup2-outer" data-index="2" class="p0_labelGroup-outer" transform="translate(133.95243961421144,100.15179081697306)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentMainLabel2-outer" class="p0_segmentMainLabel-outer" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Cambio de formato</text><text id="p0_segmentValue2-outer" class="p0_segmentValue-outer" dy="14" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(173, 173, 173);">1.42</text></g><g id="p0_labelGroup3-outer" data-index="3" class="p0_labelGroup-outer" transform="translate(195.13468178160343,71.15179081697306)" style="opacity: 1;"><text id="p0_segmentMainLabel3-outer" class="p0_segmentMainLabel-outer" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Averia en la linea</text><text id="p0_segmentValue3-outer" class="p0_segmentValue-outer" dy="14" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; fill: rgb(173, 173, 173);">1.08</text></g></g><g class="p0_tooltips"><g class="p0_tooltip" id="p0_tooltip0" style="opacity: 0;"><rect rx="2" ry="2" x="-4" opacity="0.5" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" width="154" height="19" y="-13"/><text fill="#efefef" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial;">Desconocido: 9.92 horas (49%)</text></g><g class="p0_tooltip" id="p0_tooltip1" style="opacity: 0;"><rect rx="2" ry="2" x="-4" opacity="0.5" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" width="140" height="19" y="-13"/><text fill="#efefef" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial;">Descanso: 7.92 horas (39%)</text></g><g class="p0_tooltip" id="p0_tooltip2" style="opacity: 0;"><rect rx="2" ry="2" x="-4" opacity="0.5" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" width="176" height="19" y="-13"/><text fill="#efefef" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial;">Cambio de formato: 1.42 horas (7%)</text></g><g class="p0_tooltip" id="p0_tooltip3" style="opacity: 0;"><rect rx="2" ry="2" x="-4" opacity="0.5" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" width="167.8125" height="19" y="-13"/><text fill="#efefef" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: arial;">Averia en la linea: 1.08 horas (5%)</text></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: So the strange grey rectangle disappears if you remove the `<defs>` element?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yes, it disappears, but then the graph isn't correctly drawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

It wasn't `<defs>` tags, it was the `g` tag, the one with `class="tooltip"`.
Just add `display:none` and it disapears.

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd if it is your radial gradients that it is rendering.  It's not even obvious how you would render a gradient on it's own.

Try adding `display="none"` to the `<defs>` element.  **This will affect rendering on some browsers**, but *might* work around any TCPDF bug.  Assuming that is the cause, and you don't need the SVGs to work in browsers also.

Comment: adding display:none would stop CSS from working on the content and as things like stop colours are CSS properties doing that tends to break things. The SVG spec says what you suggest should work but it's not terribly compatible with how browsers are implemented in this regard.

Comment: It worked in Chrome when I tested, but you are right, adding `display="none"` did break rendering in FF.  I will alter my answer.

Comment: I have to edit, it worked at first but now it is looking like this: http://s33.postimg.org/g3ofo3767/chart.png

Comment: I have also tried `visibility:hidden;` and it doesn't work.